# Two versions of counting leaves in a Tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

What's the difference between these two versions?

```
public static int countLeaves(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0; 
    } else
        return 1 + countLeaves(root.left) + countLeaves(root.right);   
}  

public static int countLeaves(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0; 
    } else if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return countLeaves(root.left) + countLeaves(root.right);   
}
```

I couldn't find anything that use the first version in the internet.
Is the first version wrong?

I have tried to trace them on paper, they seem to be the same.
But I just want to be sure.

Comment: When you run it, does the first version give the correct results?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I tested a few cases, yes.

Comment: I don't think they can give the same results.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first seems to count all nodes in a tree, whereas the second one one counts all leafs.

Indeed in the first one, the recursion stops when there is no valid tree anymore (`root == null`) and it always goes into recursion checking the left and right tree by adding `1` (for the current node).

The second only counts the leafs using the condition `if (root.left == null && root.right == null)`.

That's assuming a leaf is identified as node that has a `null` `root.left` and a `null` `root.right`.

Answer (score 1):

The first version is not counting leaves - it's counting nodes.

The second version is indeed counting leaves.

These methods will *not* return the same result, here's an example:

```
    root(5)
    /     \
leaf(3)   leaf(7)
```

for such a tree the first method will return 3 (number of nodes) and the second one will return 2 (number of leafs).